# One elegant proof of the transitivity part in "Show that lexicographic order is a partial ordering on the set of strings from a poset."

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

Recently, when I self-learnt Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, I did only the even-numbered exercises which the author offers the detailed description instead of the odd ones because the odd ones and the corresponding even ones are very similar.

I has some questions about exercise 9.6-38 which is related with the partial ordering and the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Cartesian_products). The problem is

> Show that lexicographic order is a partial ordering on the set of strings from a poset.

The answer says (Here the book answer use $<$ instead of $\prec$ for the partial ordering, so I use the same convention as it)

> Reflexivity is clear from the definition. To show antisymmetry, suppose that $a_1 \ldots a_m<b_1 \ldots b_n$, and let
> $t = min(m,n)$ . This means that either $a_1 \ldots a_t<b_1 \ldots b_t$ and $m < n$, so that $b_1 \ldots b_n\not<a_1 \ldots a_m$,
> or else $a_1 \ldots a_t<b_1 \ldots b_t$, so that $b_1 \ldots b_t \not< a_1 \ldots a_t$ and hence again $b_1 \ldots b_n\not<a_1 \ldots a_m$. Finally for
> **transitivity**, suppose that $a_1 \ldots a_m<b_1 \ldots b_n < c_1 \ldots c_p$. Let $t = min(m,n) , r = min(n,p) , s = min(m,p)$ ,
> and $l = min(m,n,p)$ . Now if $a_1 \ldots a_l<b_1 \ldots b_l <c_1 \ldots c_l$
> , then clearly  $ a_1 \ldots a_m < c_1 \ldots c_p $ . Otherwise,
> **without loss of generality** we may assume that  $ a_1 \ldots a_l = b_1 \ldots b_l $ . **If** $ l=t, $  then $ m<n  $ and $m \le p$.
> Furthermore, either  $ b_1 \ldots b_r < c_1 \ldots c_r $  , or  $ b_1 \ldots b_r = c_1 \ldots c_r $  and $n < p$. In the **former** case, **if** $ r>l, $  then
> since $ p>m  $ we have  $ a_1 \ldots a_m < c_1 \ldots c_p $ , whereas **if** $ r=l, $  then  $ a_1 \ldots a_l < c_1 \ldots c_l $ . In the **latter** case,
> $ a_1 \ldots a_s = c_1 \ldots c_s $  and $ m<p, $  so again  $ a_1 \ldots a_m < c_1 \ldots c_p $ . **If** $ l<t, $  then we must have  $ b_1 \ldots b_l < c_1 \ldots c_l $ ,
> whence  $ a_1 \ldots a_l < c_1 \ldots c_l $ .

My main confusion here is the "without loss of generality". Since the predicates are $a_1 \ldots a_m<b_1 \ldots b_n$ and $b_1 \ldots b_n < c_1 \ldots c_p$, the $b_1 \ldots b_l = c_1 \ldots c_l$ can be generalized from $a_1 \ldots a_l = b_1 \ldots b_l$ due to they are targeted at **one assumed relation** each. But $a_1 \ldots a_l = c_1 \ldots c_l$ may not because the relation between $a$ and $c$ is what to be proved.

But after some thoughts I seem to clear the confusion. Here is my understanding.

1. $b_1 \ldots b_l = c_1 \ldots c_l$:
   Here I offer my variant based on the book answer to **help readers understand the book answer**.
   $$
         \text{assume } b_1 \ldots b_l = c_1 \ldots c_l.\\
         t = min(m,n) , r = min(n,p) , s = min(m,p) ,l = min(m,n,p)\Rightarrow r,t\le l\\
         \begin{cases}
           1.\; l=r(\text{correspond to the original answer }l<t)\Rightarrow n<p,m\ge (r=n) \Rightarrow r=n\\
           \Rightarrow t=n=r=l\\
           \Rightarrow
             a_1 \ldots a_t<b_1 \ldots b_t\\
             \Rightarrow
             \begin{cases}
             t=l(\text{similar to the original ans "if r = l, then ..."})&\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_l<b_1 \ldots b_l \Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_l<c_1 \ldots c_l \Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_m = c_1 \ldots c_p\\
             t<l(\text{impossible})&
             \end{cases}\\
           2.\; l=min(m,r)<r\\
           (\text{correspond to }l=t \text{ but }r=l\text{ there is included in case 1})\\
           \Rightarrow (l=t) \wedge (p,n>m)\\
           \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
             a_1 \ldots a_t<b_1 \ldots b_t &\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_l< c_1 \ldots c_l\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_m = c_1 \ldots c_p\\
             a_1 \ldots a_t=b_1 \ldots b_t,m<n &\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_l = c_1 \ldots c_l\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_m = c_1 \ldots c_p \text{ due to }p>m
           \end{cases}
         \end{cases}
         $$
2. $a_1 \ldots a_l = c_1 \ldots c_l$: Since $a_1 \ldots a_l$ and $b_1 \ldots b_l$ must be **substrings** of $a_1 \ldots a_t$ and $b_1 \ldots b_t$, so $a_1 \ldots a_l$ can only be $\preccurlyeq b_1 \ldots b_l$, similarly for $b_1 \ldots b_l$ and $c_1 \ldots c_l$. Then since they are **same length** substrings, we can directly use transitive property of the **poset**. Then $a_1 \ldots a_l \preccurlyeq b_1 \ldots b_l \preccurlyeq c_1 \ldots c_l,a_1 \ldots a_l = c_1 \ldots c_l\Rightarrow a_1 \ldots a_l = b_1 \ldots b_l = c_1 \ldots c_l$. So it is **included** in the above case and the book one.

Q:

1. Is my above interpretation of the "without loss of generality" right?
2. Is there one elegant proof of the transitivity part in this problem?